# Searching for Python MSDOS parser library

Tags: python-3.x, file, parsing, dos, file-format

Does anyone knows a good Python library to parse MSDOS files and obtain metadata and start()'s bytecodes? Like an alternative version of pefile library but for MSDOS? I can't seems to find any via Google.

If there isn't, is there a good source to refer to on MSDOS's file format? This way, I can create my own parser instead. I know there are tools like IDA Pro and Reko decompiler but I need a MSDOS file parser to automate some stuff. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Are you sure you mean MSDOS (the ancient operating system dating back to the nineteen-eighties)? Or rather the Windows Command line (`cmd`), which looks similar but is a completely different thing? (Might explain the lack of search results too)

Comment: Those 16bits binary files is what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Reko decompiler maintainer here. For what it's worth, you can use Reko's MS-DOS source code and translate it to Python. It's not a lot of code and MS-DOS executables aren't that complex to parse -- it's quite a simple format. The relevant files are:
https://github.com/uxmal/reko/blob/master/src/ImageLoaders/MzExe/ExeImageLoader.cs
https://github.com/uxmal/reko/blob/master/src/ImageLoaders/MzExe/MsdosImageLoader.cs

You could also try executing the Reko code directly from Python. The Reko binaries are available as a nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Reko.Decompiler.Runtime
Use the class `Reko.ImageLoaders.MzExe.ExeImageLoader` in the `Reko.ImageLoaders.MzExe` class. Integration could be done with http://pythonnet.github.io/